# How to create a Authlogic user via the rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, authlogic

I'm using this code:

```
User.new({:email => "guy@gmail.com",  :password => "pass", :name => "guy"}).save(false)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
AWS::S3::MissingAccessKey: You did not provide both required access keys. Please provide the access_key_id and the secret_access_key.
```

I use paperclip to store user photos to S3 but it's not required to register. Not sure why this is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Authlogic requires password_confirmation, so you need to do `new_user=User.new {|u| u.email='his@email.com', u.password=u.password_confirmation='his_password'}.save!`

Beware that such a user is not active yet. You can activate them using `new_user.activate!`

Comment: The above command was putting email, password, first name and last name in email column the following command solved it: `User.create!(email: "user@email.com", password: "user_password", password_confirmation: "user_password", first_name: 'user_first_name', last_name: 'user_last_name')`

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass on your user model code? As you save user instance by skipping all callbacks/validations, it should not give you an error for photo model. However, if you share your user and photo model code (and observer if you using), I can look into them.